# how to make hamburger menu fully visible

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

by default half of hamburger is shown, as seen at the top left corner of the screenshot. I want to display full hamburger. code is taken from https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. how can I do this?[image: screenshot]

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: I just took sample code from google. code is here https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using very old technique to create `Navigation Drawer`. Its around 4 years old code and seems `perfect` regarding `old version`.

FYI, previously this kind of UI was done using [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) with `ListView`. But now android itself officially introduced sliding panel menu by introducing a newer concept called [Navigation Drawer](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) in which we combine `DrawerLayout` and [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) to achieve the desired output.

> How to make hamburger menu fully visible?

**SOLUTION:**

1. Use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity` and use `AppCompat` theme to achieve your desired output.
2. Use `NavigationView` instead of `ListView`.

**Here is an example of `NavigationView`:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <!-- Your contents -->

     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/navigation"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is a very good tutorial: [Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Hope this will help~